# Issues in using Flask-Upload

Tags: python, flask

I am using **Flask-Upload** module and for that I have installed Flask-Upload packages from

```
pip install -e "git://github.com/FelixLoether/flask-uploads#egg=Flask-Uploads"
```

and import module like this:

```
from flask.ext.uploads import UploadSet, configure_uploads, IMAGES,UploadNotAllowed
```

but it gives me error that `ImportError: No module named flask.ext.uploads`

pls tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Here is pip freeze result :

```
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy==1.0
-e git://github.com/FelixLoether/flask-uploads@d73fb8c8a4859019265e62f27e168a8bb09abfd5#egg=Flask_Uploads-dev
Jinja2==2.7
MarkupSafe==0.18
MySQL-python==1.2.4
ProxyTypes==0.9
PyYAML==3.10
SQLAlchemy==0.9.3
```

Comment: Did you use the correct `pip`? Did it install the `flask_upload` module in the same Python used for your Flask application?

Comment: yse , I have editedmy question with pip freeze result

Comment: That just means the Python setup that `pip` installs for has the packages. Do you know for certain that that is the same Python setup that runs your Flask server?

Comment: Its working now , but now I am getting this error storage must be a werkzeug.FileStorage

Answer (score 4):

Your git address is wrong. Just use:

```
pip install flask-uploads
```

Besides, change imports to this:

```
from flask_uploads import UploadSet, configure_uploads
```

Answer (score 3):

Just do:

```
pip install Flask-Uploads
```

In past I had a similar problem, but It was a diferent version installed from a version in code, and the message was the same: `ImportError: No module named flaskext.uploads`. I fixed after do this (two options):

- Install an old version of Flask-Uploads in your virtualenv:

  `pip install Flask-Uploads==0.1.3` and keep the imports: `from flaskext.uploads` in your code.
- Install or update to the last version of Flask-Uploads and change the imports:

  `pip install Flask-Uploads --upgrade` and change the imports for: `from flask.ext.uploads` in your code. Realize that now have a dot (.) flask.ext